# Angular 2 RC5 Child module to use parent router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I was trying to create two modules with new RC5 angular version. So I need to access parent `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from child module that I include in the parent one. [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/TFsCEIOfATxo1qX0gn2r?p=preview) is an example of this functionality.

As for new angular documentation, there is no need to:

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
```

Have someone tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two things:

1) The ChildModule should only use `RoutingModule.forChild(routes)` not the forRoot() version.  This is what causes the immediate error about unable to find the router outlet.

2) The main module will not properly initialize the Router unless it has some routing defined by itself.  So you need to have some routing.

In this plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/guvFUrC7mQWFmmIl6S2h/ I added an empty component to map to from the main AppModule, then overrode the path with the ChildModule routing.

**Edit**

To be clear, in your final application, I don't think it is correct to have an empty mapping like this.  If you have a router-outlet you should probably have some default real-life page to put in there.  I created the face route just to make the example work.